# Append condition to current query

Tags: php, mysqli

For example, we have a `mysqli` query for `select`:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE cat = 1";
```

And want to append some extra `query` to above query based on `query string`, I tried something like this: *(This is just sample, not my Original code)*

```
$keyw = $_GET["k"];

if($keyw){
$cleanKeyw = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $keyw);

$addQ= "AND name LIKE '%$cleanKeyw%' OR text LIKE '%$cleanKeyw%'";
} else {
$addQ= "";  
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE cat = 1 $addQ";
```

Not this one, I almost have 10 more `statment` that want to append to current `query`

I want to add `query` if `k` query string is set, it works but I want to be sure, is it safe or right way to do this? because it's based on my logic and I'm newbie on `php` and don't know there is technical way to do this?

Also I want to know is there a way to do this via `prepared statments` ?

Comment: That's what I'm using! Good question!

Comment: Yes you can build dynamic queries with prepared statements. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6635824/2960971 ... but a lot easier with PDO, as the bind process is much more fluid/accepting.

Comment: An external article guide (result from google): [Dynamically Bind Params in Prepared Statements with MySQLi](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately most answers to this will be too broad. There is no right or wrong way, and you have escaped your inputs (which is great).

You could consider building your wheres as an array, then imploding them together.

```
$wheres = [];

$wheres[] = 'cat = 1';

if ($keyw) {
    // escape etc
    $wheres[] = 'name LIKE '%$cleanKeyw%' OR text LIKE '%$cleanKeyw%''
}

$wheres = implode(" AND ", $wheres);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE $wheres";
```

You could then add lots more `$wheres[]` as you go along.